# Sending MQTT messages to Orion Context broker

Tags: mqtt, iot, fiware, fiware-orion

I have a relatively simple switch that sends data whenever the button is pressed (either 1 or 0). The message protocol it uses is MQTT. It is connected to Mosquitto via Wi-Fi and successfully sends data to it (i am able to see it using `mosquitto_sub -v -t "#"`. However, I would like to be able to send this data to Orion Context Broker and then receive it using REST commands and store it using Fiware-Cygnus afterwards.

the topic that sensor publishes messages to is `tt/sergo/demo/sw`

the name of the sensor presented in mosquitto_sub when sensor is first connected: DMS-A01

the IP - address of sensor: 192.168.0.108

I have installed Iot-Agent UL, which is working, but I don't know how to make it listen to the specific sensor that sends data to Mosquitto.
I read the manuals but either missed something or did not find the solution to my problem.
I tried using the manual below, but could not apply it to my problem.

[Connecting "thing" to Fiware](http://secmotic.com/blog/connect-thing-mqtt-ultralight-fiware/)

Thank you in advance, stack overflow community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before sending measures you need to do a provision operation for the device using the IOTA-UL API. That provision operation "creates" the device in the IOTA-UL and map it with the corresponding entity at CB. Then, you can start sending  measures using MQTT.

You can have a look to [this piece of documentation](http://fiware-iot-stack.readthedocs.io/en/master/device_api/index.html) for more detail.

Comment: thank you for your respond!
should "entity-type" always remain "thing" in provisioning?
Also, in my case, is `/tt` an API key (and if yes, then do i need to change in in config.js file afterwards)? or since it is not mentioned, it remains default?

Comment: Thank you! Everything worked in the end. I really had to provision the device and then just match the topic names I publish with the one that IoTAgent should receive.

Comment: Good to know it! :)